# remove empty strings in an array before this.setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Initial state**

```
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: {
        id: 0,
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        phoneNumbers: ['', '', ''],
      }
    };
  }
```

**my handleInputChange function:**

```
  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { user } = this.state;
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;

    if (name === 'contactNumber1') {
      user.phoneNumbers[0] = value;
    } else if (name === 'contactNumber2') {
      user.phoneNumbers[1] = value;
    } else if (name === 'contactNumber3') {
      user.phoneNumbers[2] = value;
      console.log('hellooo', user.phoneNumbers);
    } else {
      user[name] = value;
    }
    const filteredPhoneNumbers = user.phoneNumbers.filter(e => e !== '');
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      user: {
        ...prevState.user,
        [name]: value,
        phoneNumbers: [...filteredPhoneNumbers],
      },
    }));
  }
```

*When I remove an element, the element in the index above populates the element I just deleted What am I missing?*
* I am getting this error because of my code too - A component is changing a controlled input of type undefined to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component*

Answer (score 0):

You could try parsing "this.state" like this:

```
const { user } = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state));
```

I think you're referencing the same object to the user cons

Comment: changing const { user } = this.state; to const { user } = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state)); breaks the code? do I have to do something else?

Comment: Or use just user.phoneNumbers.push(value) instead of user.phoneNumbers[0] = value;